# VUE: how to use watch with vue get and set composition api

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, watch, vue-composition-api, vuetifyjs3

I am trying to create a searchable table element where user can also search and filter the returned result. but i can't seem to get how to set the value in the computed property setter.

but I keep getting tons of errors like:
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

```
import { watch } from "vue";
import { computed, ref, reactive } from "vue";
import { useStore } from "vuex";



const searchText = ref("");
watch(searchText, () => filterHistory());
const user = computed(() => store.getters["profile/getProfile"]);

const reversedHistory = computed({
  get() {
    return user.value.history.reverse();
  },
  set(value) {
    reversedHistory.value = value;
  },
});


const filterHistory = () => {
  let newHistory = reversedHistory.value.filter(
    (item) => searchText === item.person
  );
  rerturn newHistory
};
```

Comment: You're setting  reversedHistory.value inside  reversedHistory setter. That's recursion

Comment: so it should be user.value.history = value; ?

Comment: It's not a good idea overall to mutate a getter. It's unknown what's user.value.history. What's store? Is it vuex? The question doesn't mention this, this is relevant. You need to have vuex mutation to explicitly modify a store

Comment: yes, it's vuex, i've updated the query,

Answer (score 1):

`reversedHistory` changes itself inside a setter, this results in recursion.

Considering that user history is expected to be used from store, it makes sense to have relevant Vuex getter like `profile/getHistory`.

It's generally incorrect to mutate read-only computed, as it can discard the changes on the next update.

Vuex state isn't supposed to be mutated outside a store, there's supposed to be  an action or mutation.

It could be:

```
const reversedHistory = computed({
  get() {
    return store.getters["profile/getHistory"]).reverse();
  },
  set(value) {
    store.commit('profile/setHistory', value.reverse());
  },
});
```

Comment: oh oh, I get you complete, this completely make sense, what i was trying to avoid was too much state updates. i was trying to create a temporary variable to hold changes instead of hitting the store for each key press, but i'll work with this, thank you so much, makes a lot of sense.